# Javascript colour changer only changing colour on second click?

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a navbar and i am trying to make it so it highlights the current tab, however my javascript isnt working, it only works on the second click, and only if you double click.

```js
function navColourChange(id){
  var navBarLinks=document.getElementsByClassName("navLinks");
  for(i=0;i<navBarLinks.length;i++){
    navBarLinks[i].style.borderTop = "thick solid #ffffFF";
    navBarLinks[i].style.color="#2F2933"
    console.log(i)
  }
  var link = navBarLinks[id]
  link.style.borderTop = "4px solid #01A2A6";
  link.style.color="#01A2A6"
}
```

```html
<div class="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html" id="navButton1" class="navLinks" onclick="navColourChange(0)">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="about.html" id="navButton3" class="navLinks" onclick="navColourChange(1)">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="Portfolio.html" id="navButton4" class="navLinks" onclick="navColourChange(2)">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="Contact.html" id="navButton2" class="navLinks" onclick="navColourChange(3)">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Heres what it looks [like](https://gyazo.com/b2a7970fff19cef854701c8ea62ca133)

Comment: does the first click navigate to about.html etc? Or are you disabling default functionality elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes it takes me to the right page.

Comment: does the color change before the page navigates? you won't see the color on the new page...

Comment: @user7432478 when the page **navigates to a new page / reloads** that means JS reloads too. You need to store somewhere the active address (cookie or localStorage) or get the address of the current page and target the `href` attribute that matches the current page...

Comment: Trying using target="_blank" on your links. Then look at your original page. The tab should have changed.

Comment: That makes alot of sense how it changes when you navigate. And yes when you navigate with target="_blank" the colour has changed.

Comment: As mentioned, when you reload the page, whatever you did with javascript goes away. That's why you see the border flash. I suggest instead of doing this with javascript, you could add a css class to your body on each of those pages and based the border color on that class existing on your body.

Comment: Yes Roko is correct, rather than having an onclick handler on your link, have your page determine what tab it is on load and style correctly on initialization. But if you have separate html files for each page anyway why not just style each page with the correct tab highlighted, no JS required?

Comment: I will do that now, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @user7432478 also instead of using inline JS and stuff like `id="navButton1" class="navLinks"` simply JS loop a class and use `addEventListener`, reference than to the clicked element using `this` like `this.getAttribute("href")` etc...

Comment: If you click a link like "CONTACT" the color is changing but your go to another page. On "Contact.html" you click again and it changes color because you are already on this page.

Answer (score 0):

If what you really are looking for is a way to highligt the current page in your navbar, with JavaScript/jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$(function() {
   var currentPage = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
   $('.NavBar ul li a[href*="'+currentPage+'"]').css({
      borderTop: "4px solid #01A2A6",
      color: "#01A2A6"
   });
});
```

Here we find the filename from the url and then style that a-element in the navbar which has that filename as href.